# creating a custom list windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8.1

here is the code adding data to the list, after which i return the list. Problem is that the last set of data seems to be overwriting everything else in the list

```
           for (int k=0; k < jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray().Count; k++)
                {

                    //add the corresponding data from the sample array
                    obj.accountNumber = jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray()[k].GetObject()["id"].GetString();
                    obj.accountName = jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray()[k].GetObject()["name"].GetString();
                    obj.accountBall = jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray()[k].GetObject()["age"].GetString();
                    mylist.Add(obj);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You always add the same object `obj` to the list. You need to create a new in the top of the loop.

```
       for (int k=0; k < jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray().Count; k++)
            { 
                obj = new ObjectType(); // you know better the type of the object you want to create. 

                //add the corresponding data from the sample array
                obj.accountNumber = jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray()[k].GetObject()["id"].GetString();
                obj.accountName = jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray()[k].GetObject()["name"].GetString();
                obj.accountBall = jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray()[k].GetObject()["age"].GetString();
                mylist.Add(obj);
            }
```

Without the the line `obj = new ...` you change the properties `accountNumber`, `accountName` and `accountBall` of the same object instance. At the end you add always that object reference to the list. So it seems that the last run of the loop changes *all* objects.

Comment: Thank you so much, its been bothering me for a while:)

Comment: Next step to get into StackOverflow: Accept the answer that solved your problem the most and receive the Scholar badge.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't adding any new objects to the list, it modifies and adds the same object. In the end, the list contains X references to the same object instance.

In general it is consider bad practice to declare a variable outside the scope in which it is used. You could have avoided this problem by writing:

```
var myArray=jsonObject["mydetails"].GetArray();
for (int k=0; k < myArray.Count; k++)
{
    var myJsonObject=myArray[k].GetObject();
    var obj=new MyAccountObject();        
    obj.accountNumber = myJsonObject["id"].GetString();
    ...
 }
```

Notice that instead of calling GetArray() and GetObject() in each line (essentially doing the job of extracting the array multiple times) I stored them in separate variables. This will result in far less CPU and memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for you help, also the extra tip:)